# Translating SPUserResizableView [Objective C] to Swift 3.0 setFrame setContentView

Tags: objective-c, swift, translation

Using iOS 10.20 & Swift 3.0 Want to use this excellent piece of code written by Stephen Poletto a while back in my code, but need it in Swift 3.0 really.

https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

Almost there but I am stuck right now. My code crashes cause it doesn't execute setContentView or setFrame, and I don't understand how Stephan's code calls this.. I see no reference to either of there methods in his code? do they called when he sets a frame or view perhaps? What is the Swift equivient? I recoded the methods, but their not be executed...

```
- (void)setContentView:(UIView *)newContentView {
  [contentView removeFromSuperview];
  contentView = newContentView;
  contentView.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset + kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset + kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2);
  [self addSubview:contentView];

  // Ensure the border view is always on top by removing it and adding it to the end of the subview list.
  [borderView removeFromSuperview];
  [self addSubview:borderView];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {
  [super setFrame:newFrame];
  contentView.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset + kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset + kSPUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize/2);
  borderView.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset, kSPUserResizableViewGlobalInset);
  [borderView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

My Swift 3.0 code looks like this?

```
 func setContentView(newContentView: UIView) {
    contentView.removeFromSuperview()
    contentView = newContentView
    contentView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0, dy: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0)
    self.addSubview(contentView)

    // Ensure the border view is always on top by removing it and adding it to the end of the subview list.
    borderView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.addSubview(borderView)
    }

    func setFrame(newFrame: CGRect) {
      contentView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0, dy: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0)
      borderView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset), dy: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset));
      borderView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Here is a partial answer, this is how you override setFrame in Swift it seems; found the answer on reddit.

```
 override var frame: CGRect {
    get {
        return super.frame
    }
    set (newFrame) {
        super.frame = newFrame
        contentView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0, dy: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset) + kUserResizableViewInteractiveBorderSize / 2.0)
        borderView.frame = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset), dy: CGFloat(kUserResizableViewGlobalInset));
        borderView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

At least it partly works. I am step closer! Would use the same method for setContentView but figuring out the syntax on that is still eluding me right now.